# Should I separate interval data from single data to two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a data table where I collect all kinds of data. In some cases it's an interval and in other cases it's just a single value.

Should I use the same table for both types or separate it into two different tables?

**Example - Single**

```
1, hat_price, 15, USD
```

**Example - Interval**

```
2, hat_history, 2015-01-01, date, 2018, year
```

Except from the interval, in this case a date, it's also affecting the suffix.

**A table could look like this:**

```
id, key, value, suffix, min_value, min_suffix, max_value, max_suffix
```

**Then the new data would look something like this:**

Because of the blanks.

```
1, hat_price, 15, USD, , , ,
2, hat_history, , , 2015-01-01, date, 2018, year
```

Is this the best way or should I split them into two tables?

Comment: These rows don't look related at all.  One has a price and one has a date range.  They should probably go in separate tables.

Comment: In your case better way will be splitting them into seperate tables. Because data is not related to each other. With two tables it gets more clear to understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes. None of the data looks related. I have data like email (single value), phone (single value), banks (multiple values), address (text), open times (interval of hours). I can't have a table for each type. About 50 different values like that.

Comment: @ikram That's kind of my problem. I have so many different kind of data, like 50. I can't have 50 different tables. It would be to overdo it.

Comment: Can you explain in detail. For ex: How email, phone and address datas in one row are not related in your case?

Comment: @ikram You are right. I need to rethink the table structure and not just think in rows, but also on columns. (by the way ikram means "I hug you" in swedish) =)